# Reference a TextView @id in two seperate layout files?

Tags: android, xml, textview, expandablelistview

Is there a way to create an instance of a TextView on a **separate layout**? I have created an ExpandableListView with x number of objects. I would like to display one of the children in the collapsed group as well. I realize I could set up in the code, however it would be much easier, and much cleaner if I could just point to the same id R.id.dscItem multiple times.

I have tried dropping the + in "@+id/dscItem"so that it was "@id/dscItem" but it didn't do much. Is it true that I can only point to this id once!?

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this, createGroup(), R.layout.exprow, R.layout.row,
            new String[] { Items.ITEMS_ITEM }, new int[] { R.id.txtItem },
            createChildren(), R.layout.exprow, new String[] {
                    Items.ITEMS_DESC, Items.ITEMS_MANU },
            new int[] { R.id.dscItem, R.id.manuItem });
```

XML layout 1:

```
></TextView>
<TextView 
android:text="Description" 
android:id="@id/dscItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
android:textSize="15dip"

></TextView>
```

XML layout 2

```
<TextView 
android:text="Description" 
android:id="@+id/dscItem" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#994020"
android:layout_gravity="right"

></TextView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a textview in a separate layout and use it by layout merge in xml or layout inflater in java code
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Comment: Works well. However, I didn't actually need to create  <merge/>, I just needed to add <include layout="......"/> inside of my linearlayout. Thanks for the lead!